# FIBplus для Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi

Доброе всем время суток.
Есть честно купленные FIBplus и Delphi XE2. Стоит срочная задача их подружить, так как разработчики FIBplus пока не торопятся обновлять свой продукт для совместимости с последней Delphi.

После правки FIBPlus.inc добавлением директивы Ver230, остались однотипные ошибки при компиляции модуля pFIBLists:

```
[DCC Error] pFIBLists.pas(389): E2017 Pointer type required
```

Строка, содержащая ошибку:

```
 if MaxValue<Integer(FList.List^[Index1]) then Dec(Index1);
```

Курсор становится перед [Index1]
Как я понял, компилятору что-то не понравилось с адресацией памяти.
Так как все еще не силен в этом, прошу вашей помощи.

```
procedure TSortedList.IncValuesDiapazon(FromValue,ToValue:integer; Distance:integer);
var
    i     :integer;
    Index :integer;
    Index1:integer;
    MaxValue:integer;
    MinValue:integer;

begin
 if FList.Count=0 then Exit;
 if FromValue>ToValue then
 begin
   MaxValue:=FromValue;
   MinValue:=ToValue;
 end
 else
 begin
   MaxValue:=ToValue;
   MinValue:=FromValue;
 end;
 Find(MinValue, Index);
 Find(MaxValue, Index1);
 if Index1>=FList.Count then  Index1:=FList.Count-1;
 if MaxValue<Integer(FList.List^[Index1]) then Dec(Index1);

 for i:=Index1 downto Index do
   FList.List^[i]:=Pointer(Integer(FList.List^[i])+Distance)

end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Блин, как всегда, стоит спросить, как сам в тот же момент находишь ответ.

Все дело в том, что в Delphi XE TList вот такой:

```
  TList = class(TObject)
    ...
    property List: PPointerList read FList;
  end;
```

А в Delphi XE2 такой:

```
  TList = class(TObject)
    ...
    property List: TPointerList read FList;
  end;
```

То есть крышка для разыменовывания в коде лишняя.

Comment: Ну что, получилось подружить? У меня выдаёт `access violation` на подключении к базе.

Comment: Попробуйте http://narod.ru/disk/28021707001/fibplus_dxe2.rar.html

Comment: После того, как недостающие файлы добавил из своей коллекции ругнулся на `pFIBDataSet.pas`. Я его поправил, установил, но при подключении та же ошибка, что и прошлый раз `access violation`... у меня версия фибплюс 7.0.15, а сервера 2.5.

Comment: Упс, простите, в архиве FIB версии 7.1. <br>У меня работает без проблем именно с Firebird 2.5. <br>Скачайте с оф.сайта триальную версию, установите, распакуйте файлы из архива в папку установки с перезаписью уже установленных файлов, установите компоненты из среды.

Comment: Кстати, нашел, в своих "исправлениях" ошибку. Но выкладывать думаю не стоит - подождем все же официальный релиз.

Comment: В связи с выходом новой версии FIBplus удаляю ранее выложенные мною поделки